# Application of the Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: measure-theory

Let $p > 2$ and $c > 0$. Then the set
$$
 \left \{ x \in [0,1] : \left | x-\frac aq\right | \leq \frac c {q^p} \text{ for infinitly many $a,q \in \mathbb N^*$ } \right \}
$$ has measure zero. Recall the Borel-Cantelli Lemma:

If $\Omega_1,\Omega_2,\cdots$ are measurable subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(\Omega_n) < \infty$ then the set
$$
 \left \{ x \in \mathbb R^n : x \in \Omega_n \text{ for infinitly many } n \right \}
$$ has measure zero.

This is by the way Tao Exercise 19.2.7.

Comment: What is the question? How to define the $\Omega_k$ so that the first set is the set of $x$ that lie in infinitely many $\Omega_k$?

Comment: That would be helpful to me. Then I could check wether the sum of the measures does converge or not.

Comment: Let $$A(a,q) := \left[\frac{a}{q} - \frac{c}{q^p},\, \frac{a}{q} + \frac{c}{q^p}\right]$$ and $$\Omega_n = \bigcup_{a=0}^{n+1} A(a,n+1).$$

Comment: Could you explain your soultion. I don't understand the conditions. Must we have $A(a,q) \subseteq [0,1]$ ?

Comment: I think we just must cover $[0,1]$ because $x \in [0,1]$. Then for fixed $q$ we can assume $0 \leq a \leq q$ because otherwise $x \notin A(a,q)$ . Is that correct ?

Comment: You can intersect the $A(a,q)$ with $[0,\,1]$, but that is not necessary. We take $0\leqslant a \leqslant q$, since if $x \in [0,\,1]$ satisfies $\left\lvert x - \frac{k}{q}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{c}{q^p}$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, it also satisfies the inequality for the $a$ in the range $0,\,\ldots,\,q$ closest to $k$. For large enough $q$, the $A(a,q)$ don't overlap, then it's clear that only $0 \leqslant a \leqslant q$ is possible.

Comment: This exercise still confuses me. Sorry but you mean if $\left |x - \frac k q \right| \leq \frac c {q^p}$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$ then this implies $\left | x - \frac a q \right |\leq \frac c {q^p}$ with $0 \leq a \leq q$ and $a$ s.t. $|a-k| = \min_{0 \leq i \leq q} |i - k|$ ?

Comment: I mean that if $x \in [0,\,1]$, and $x \in A(k,q)$ for some $k < 0$, then also $x \in A(0,q)$, and if $x \in A(k,q)$ for some $k > q$, then $x \in A(q,q)$. Simply because $A(0,q)$ reaches farther up, and $A(q,q)$ farther down than $A(k,q)$ for $k < 0$ resp. $k > q$.

Comment: A complete answer or reference would be great. As far as is see you say $A(k,q) \subseteq A(q,q)$ if $k > q$. But I can't see why this sould be true i.e. they have the same length and so they should be equal.

Comment: No, I say $\bigl(A(k,q) \cap [0,\,1]\bigr) \subset \bigl(A(q,q) \cap [0,\,1]\bigr)$ for $k > q$. Let me write it up.

Comment: Ok now I get it. Then we have that my original set is a subset of  $\{ x \in [0,1]: x \in \Omega_n \text{ for infinitly many } n \}$ which has measure zero and thus my original set has measure zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any pair $(a,q)$ of positive integers, let

$$A(a,q) := \left[\frac{a}{q}-\frac{c}{q^p},\, \frac{a}{q} + \frac{c}{q^p}\right]$$

the interval consisting of those $x$ that satisfy the inequality

$$\left\lvert x - \frac{a}{q}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{c}{q^p}\tag{1}$$

for that particular pair. Then

$$\Omega_q = \bigcup_{a = 1}^q A(a,q) \cap [0,\,1]$$

is the set of $x \in [0,\,1]$ that satisfy $(1)$ for $q$ and some positive $a$, since for $a > q$, we have $\bigl(A(a,q)\cap[0,\,1]\bigr) \subset \bigl(A(q,q)\cap[0,\,1]\bigr)$.

Then $$\left \{ x \in [0,1] : \left | x-\frac aq\right | \leq \frac c {q^p} \text{ for infinitely many $a,q \in \mathbb N^*$ } \right \}$$

is the set of $x \in [0,\,1]$ belonging to infinitely many $\Omega_q$,

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcup_{q=n}^\infty \Omega_q\right).$$

Now, $m\left(A(a,q)\right) \leqslant \frac{2c}{q^p}$, and hence $m(\Omega_q) \leqslant \frac{2cq}{q^p} = \frac{2c}{q^{p-1}}$, and

$$\sum_{q=1}^\infty m(\Omega_q) \leqslant 2c \sum_{q=1}^\infty \frac{1}{q^{p-1}} < \infty,$$

since $p > 2$.

Comment: Only $m(\Omega_q) \leq \frac {2c (q+1)} {q^p}$ but the result sill remains true.

Comment: In the comments, I had $\Omega_q$ consist of $q+1$ $A(a,q)$, but when writing the answer I noticed the constraint $a > 0$, so now I have only $q$ parts making up $\Omega_q$. $A(0,q)$ no longer appears.

Comment: What is $A(0,q) \cap [0,1] = [0, \frac c {q^p} ]$ then a subset of ?

Comment: We don't need it, since the problem only asks for $x$ which satisfy $\left\lvert x - \frac{a}{q}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{c}{q^p}$ for (infinitely many) $a,q\in \mathbb{N}^\ast$. We can include it, if we wish, to get a slightly larger set, and then have the bound $\frac{2c(q+1)}{q^p}$ for $\Omega_q$, which, as you noted, doesn't change anything relevant.

Comment: Small correction: $\left(A(a,q) \cap [0,1] \right) \subset \left(A(q,q) \cap [0,1] \right) $ should be $ \dots \subset \left(A(b,q) \cap [0,1] \right)$ where $b > 0$ is the least residue of $a \pmod{q}.$

Comment: @Dzoooks No, $A(q,q)$ is correct there. We have $A(q,q) \cap [0,1] = \bigl[ 1 - \frac{c}{q^p}, 1\bigr]$, and for $a > q$ of course $\frac{a}{q} - \frac{c}{q^p] \geqslant 1 - \frac{c}{q^p}$. But if we take for example $a = q+1$ with $q > 3$ and $p = 3$, $c = 2q^2$, then $1 \in A(q+1,q) \cap [0,1]$, but $1 \notin A(1,q) \cap [0,1] = \bigl[0, \frac{3}{q}\bigr]$.

Comment: Ah, of course with $\cap [0,1]$ most of them are $\emptyset$; now I see what you meant.