# Diophantine approximation and Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, diophantine-approximation

> Show that the set of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that there are infinitely many fractions p/q with p,q
>   relatively prime integers and $|x-p/q|\le1/q^3$ has Lebesgue measure zero.

I know how to show this for $x\in[0,1]$ by using Borel-Cantelli. Now my questions are:

> - How can I show this for $x\in\mathbb{R}$?
> - Is there a way to show this without using Borel-Cantelli?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Presumably, if you can do it for $[0,1]$, you can do it for $[n,n+1]$ for each integer $n$. Then the measure of a union of countably many sets of measure zero....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application of the Borel-Cantelli Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476552/application-of-the-borel-cantelli-lemma)