# Borel-Cantelli lemma in diophantine approximation

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, measure-theory

Prove, that the set of those $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists infinitely many fractions $\frac{p}{q}$, with relatively prime integers $p$ and $q$ such that $$\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|\leq \frac{1}{q^3}$$ is a set of measure zero.

**My solution:** Let's fix $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ and consider the following set for each $q\in \mathbb{N}$: $$E_{p,q}=\left( \frac{p}{q}-\frac{1}{q^3},\frac{p}{q}+\frac{1}{q^3}\right).$$
We see that $E_{p,q}$ is measurable and $m(E_{p,q})=\dfrac{2}{q^3}$, where $m$ - Lebesgue measure. Also note that $\sum \limits_{q=1}^{\infty}m(E_{p,q})=\sum \limits_{q=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{q^3}<\infty$. Let's use the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Then $E_p:=\limsup \limits_{q\to \infty} E_{p,q}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: x \ \text{belongs to infinitely many} \ E_{p,q}\}$ has zero measure, i.e. $m(E_p)=0$. Then $E=\bigcup \limits_{p=1}^{\infty}E_p$ has alzo zero measure.

I know that this question appeared many times in MSE but please do not close it since many solutions I have seen is a bit different so that's why I've created topic in order to know is my solution correct or not?

Would be very grateful for feedback.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is the collection of all coprime $p,q$ with $q>0$. Then you need $\limsup_{(p,q) \in A} E_{p,q}$ which is different than the set $E$ (which is contained in the $\limsup$). (Also, though this is minor, the $E_{p,q}$ should be closed intervals.) The problem with this approach is that it is not clear that $\sum_{(p,q) \in A} m(E_{p,q})$ is bounded, so we can't apply Borel Cantelli.

Comment: The cute part of Daniel's solution https://math.stackexchange.com/a/476901/27978 is to deal with the $x$ that lie in a bounded interval, this allows the $p$ to be bounded by a multiple of $q$ in $E_{p,q}$ and so we get summability.

Comment: Just to elaborate, it is not necessarily true that $\limsup_{p,q} E_{p,q} = \cup_p \limsup_q E_{p,q}$. It is true that $\cup_p \limsup_q E_{p,q} \subset \limsup_{p,q} E_{p,q}$, but this containment goes in the 'wrong' direction.