# Another application of Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: measure-theory

Let $c>0$ and $P(x)$ be a polynomial. Then there exists a $p>1$ (e.g. we can take $p$ to be greater than the degree of $P$) such that for almost all $x=e^{2\pi i\theta}, \theta \in [0,1]$ on the unit circle, $\left|P(x^N)\right|<\frac{c}{N^p}$ occurs only for finitely many $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

We can show this for $P(x)=x-1$. $P(x^N) =|x^N-1|=|e^{2\pi iN\theta}-1|=|e^{2\pi i(N\theta-m)}-1| \sim{|N\theta-m|}$ where $m$ is the closest integer to $N\theta$. For any $p>1$, applying [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476552/application-of-the-borel-cantelli-lemma/476901#476901) proved by Borel-Cantelli Lemma gives the result.

For general $P(x)$, we only need to factorize $P(x)$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and analyse the factors similarly.

I believe similar result also holds for any multivariate polynomial $P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$.

Could you prove this or give a reference please? Thanks.